# Relacionar 2 tablas en R

Tags: r, rstudio

Buenas tardes,

Quería saber que función debo tomar para poder relacionar en R dos tablas (tabla 1, en la que tengo todos mis datos brutos de mis especies y tabla 2, en la que tengo un índice con especies representativas). La idea es añadir un valor (1 por ejemplo) a las especies de la tabla 1 que también aparecen en la tabla 2 y otro valor (0 por ejemplo) a aquellas especies que aparecen en la tabla 1 pero no en la tabla 2.

Gracias de antemano.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adrian, no has indicado de que tipo de objeto hablas cuando mencionas "una tabla", imagino que se trata de un `data.frame`, también es bueno que plantees la pregunta con algún ejemplo. Veamos como puedes resolver lo que planteas:

```
tabla1 <- data.frame(especie = c("perro", "gato", "ratón"))
tabla2 <- data.frame(especie = c("vaca", "buitre", "perro", "ratón"))
```

Tenemos dos `data.frame` y queremos agregar una columna a `tabla1` que nos indique si la especie se encuentra en la `tabla1`, lo podemos resolver así:

```
tabla1$EstaEnTabla2 <- ifelse(is.na(match(tabla1$especie, tabla2$especie)),0,1)
```

En primer lugar usamos [`match()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/match.html) que nos devuelve un vector con la primer ocurrencia de `tabla1$especie` en `tabla2$especie` y `NA` en caso de que no existan coincidencias. Por último, usamos la función ternaria [`ifelse()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ifelse.html) con [`is.na()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/NA.html) para devolver 0 en caso que `match` sea un valor `NA` y `1` en caso contrario. Con esta simples funciones básicas terminamos con un `data.frame` como este:

```
    especie EstaEnTabla2
1   perro              1
2   gato               0
3   ratón              1
```

Comment: En primer lugar muchas gracias por tu pronta respuesta. Soy nuevo en este foro y no sabia como formular la pregunta de manera correcta. La función que me aportas funciona a la perfección.